# Finding duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates

i have data in this format of ID and the number of times it appears. i want to write a function that returns the ID apprearing more than twice.

```
  ID    Freq
  100    1
  101    1
  102    1
  103    1
  104    1
  105    2
  106    1
  107    1
  108    1
```

here is my code

```
if (data$Freq>=2){
  return(data$ID)
} else {
  print("no duplicates of years")
}
```

am getting the following anser and a warning

```
[1] "no duplicates of years"
Warning message:
In if (x$Freq > 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

what could i be doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Thanks all of u for the response. i suppose i have a problem with the way i created the frequency table

```
x=as.data.frame(table(data$cid))
```

where `cid` is the `ID`. when i try to see the elements in the first column i.e

```
> x$var1[1:20,]
```

i get NULL, while this

```
>x$Freq[1:20,]
```

would return

```
Error in x$Freq[1:20, ] : incorrect number of dimensions'
```

but `x[1:20,]` returns a dataframe showing elements in `x`.

Comment: You should use `ifelse` instead of `if`

Comment: ID appearing *more than* or *at least* twice?

Comment: Is your variable called `x` or called `data`? The error message you're giving is not consistent with your code (it also says `> 1` instead of `>= 2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andrie suggested, `ifelse` might be useful:

Based on your additional info, here's a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)

data <- as.data.frame(table(data.frame(cid = sample(100:120, 30, replace=TRUE))))

> ifelse(data$Freq-1, as.character(data$Var1), "no duplicates of years")
#  [1] "no duplicates of years" "no duplicates of years" "no duplicates of years"
#  [4] "no duplicates of years" "104"                    "105"                   
#  [7] "107"                    "108"                    "no duplicates of years"
# [10] "no duplicates of years" "113"                    "no duplicates of years"
# [13] "no duplicates of years" "116"                    "118"                   
# [16] "119"                    "no duplicates of years"
```

And to just display IDs with Freq > 1:

```
data$Var1[as.logical(data$Freq - 1)]
# [1] 104 105 107 108 113 116 118 119
# 17 Levels: 100 101 102 103 104 105 107 108 110 112 113 114 115 116 118 ... 120
```

Comment: Thanks all of u for the response. i suppose i have a problem with the way i created the frequency table

Comment: Thanks all of u for the response. i suppose i have a problem with the way i created the frequency table 'x=as.data.frame(table(data$cid)) where cid is the ID. when i try to see the elements in the first column i.e '> x$var1[1:20,] i get NULL, while this >x$Freq[1:20,] would return Error in x$Freq[1:20, ] : incorrect number of dimensions' but x[1:20,] returns a dataframe showing elements in x.'

Comment: @jonestats, please see my updated answer. Also, please read up on subsetting (`?Extract`). `x$Freq` is a 1-dimensional vector, and the comma in your square brackets indicates that you are trying to subset a 2-dimensional object.

Comment: This works and thanks a lot. i have over 10,000 cases so my screen is filled up and i can not see the first elements. can i just see the observations with more than 1 freq?

Comment: @jonestats, please see my updated answer. Also, I think your comment above finally gets at what you'd *really* like to do. And there are many ways of going about that, perhaps efficiently avoiding the `table` function altogether. For future questions, please consider including more context :)

Comment: My problem is now sorted. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 3):

There is a command `duplicated()` that will do this without reference to your $Freq column:

```
data$ID[duplicated(data$ID)]
```

Your own code does not work as the error suggests because `if()` there needs a single TRUE/FALSE condition and it will just look at the first element of data$Freq which is a 1 then stop.

If you want to do something like this then `which()` or a is what you want:

```
df= data.frame(freq=rep(1:2,5), id=1:10)

 df

   freq id
1     1  1
2     2  2
3     1  3
4     2  4
5     1  5
6     2  6
7     1  7
8     2  8
9     1  9
10    2 10

df$id[which(df$freq>1)]
[1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

or even

```
df$id[df$freq>1]
[1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the OP wants `duplicated`- look at the data and there's no indication that the ID `105` appears more than once in that vector

Comment: He says 'i want to write a function that returns the ID appearring more than twice.' I assumed his example was just incomplete and thought I'd mention the direct method.